# Make a JOIN of two separated DQLs

Tags: sql, subquery, dql, documentum, documentum6.5

Because of a limitiation on the platform, we couldn't make a sub-select of one select. This is our DQL:

```
   SELECT attr_nombre FROM lis_mindo_abogados WHERE attr_codigo_usuario in (Select attr_abogadoppal_code FROM me_mindo_mail where r_object_id='@r_object_id')
```

So, we planned to make a JOIN of this two separated DQLs:

```
   SELECT attr_abogadoppal_code, r_object_id FROM me_mindo_mail WHERE r_object_id='@r_object_id'

   SELECT attr_nombre FROM lis_mindo_abogados WHERE attr_codigo_usuario in ('CODE_ABOGADO1','CODE_ABOGADO2','CODE_ABOGADO3')
```

For one r_object_id, we have several attr_abogadoppal_code (CODE_ABOGADO1/2/3).

Does it possible to make any kind of JOIN of this two separated DQLs?

Thanks for your time and help!

Answer (score 1):

May be so:

```
SELECT l.attr_nombre
FROM lis_mindo_abogados l, me_mindo_mail m
WHERE l.attr_codigo_usuario = m.attr_abogadoppal_code
AND m.r_object_id='@r_object_id'
```

Comment: Thanks! That's the idea, but CODE_ABOGADOn is the result of the first DQL, we don't know how many results we could obtain in each case...1,5,9....

Comment: I've tested it in my DQLTester (Documentum) and says this error: "A parse Error (syntax error) has occurred in the vicinity of: SELECT l.attr_nombre FROM lis_mindo_abogados l JOIN"
Should I write an special character for Documentum queries? As far as I know, LEFT JOIN is the standard JOIN, as it is said here (http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine1/en/latest/en/manual/dql-doctrine-query-language.html).

Comment: So, I've tryed to put this one:

   SELECT l.attr_nombre
   FROM lis_mindo_abogados l
   LEFT JOIN me_mindo_mail m on l.attr_codigo_usuario = m.attr_abogadoppal_code
   AND m.r_object_id='@r_object_id'

and the error now says: [DM_QUERY_E_REPEATING_USED]error:" You have specified a repeating attribute (attr_abogadoppal_code) where is not allowed."

Any suggestion please?

Comment: I do not see any repeating conflicts in this particular query. It maybe problem somewhere in the code base. Make sure you are using table\field aliases everywhere in the code. I.e. that attr_abogadoppal_code field has table alias (X.ttr_abogadoppal_code) in all places.

Comment: http://developer-content.emc.com/developer/downloads/app_performanceNew.pdf - page 24

Comment: I rewrote the query using native join syntax

Comment: Thanks, I've tried your last suggestion, but as you said there is maybe a problem in the original documental type (Documentum). Another idea... I've tried something like this:
SELECT l.attr_nombre
FROM lis_mindo_abogados l, me_mindo_mail m
WHERE l.attr_codigo_usuario IN ( m.attr_abogadoppal_code )
AND m.r_object_id='@r_object_id'
but it says that there is a syntax problem inside the brackets...

Comment: You can try adding the `ENABLE (ROW_BASED)` hint to the end of your query as well, when you get the repeating attribute error.

Comment: @AlexMJ Doctrine Query Language from your link is NOT Documentum DQL.

Answer (score 0):

Since attr_abogadoppal_code is repeating (error messages say so), it needs the ANY keyword :

```
SELECT l.attr_nombre
FROM lis_mindo_abogados l, me_mindo_mail m
WHERE l.attr_codigo_usuario = ANY m.attr_abogadoppal_code
AND m.r_object_id='@r_object_id'
```